# Typescript: Why is number/string/... assignable to null?

Tags: typescript

Why is TypeScript only showing errors when assigning a string to a number, but not when assigning null to a number?

```js
export type ArrayWithNumberOrString = Array<number | string>;
export type ArrayWithNumberOrNull = Array<number | null>;


function doSomethingWithNumbersOnly(array: number[]): number[] {
  return array;
};

const numbersAndString: ArrayWithNumberOrString = [1, 2, 3, 'string'];
const numbersAndNull: ArrayWithNumberOrNull = [1, 2, 3, null];

doSomethingWithNumbersOnly(numbersAndString);
doSomethingWithNumbersOnly(numbersAndNull);
```

[Typescript sandbox](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Aexport%20type%20ArrayWithNumberOrString%20%3D%20Array%3Cnumber%20%7C%20string%3E%3B%0D%0Aexport%20type%20ArrayWithNumberOrNull%20%3D%20Array%3Cnumber%20%7C%20null%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20doSomethingWithNumbersOnly(array%3A%20number%5B%5D)%3A%20number%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20array%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20numbersAndString%3A%20ArrayWithNumberOrString%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%20'string'%5D%3B%0D%0Aconst%20numbersAndNull%3A%20ArrayWithNumberOrNull%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%20null%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AdoSomethingWithNumbersOnly(numbersAndString)%3B%0D%0AdoSomethingWithNumbersOnly(numbersAndNull)%3B)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And immediately found the answer:

By default the option `strictNullChecks` is disabled in tsconfig.json.